# Query Array value of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a record with one of the values stored as an array like this;

```
#<Health id: 12, district: 43, county: 89, sub_county: 480, name_of_institution: "May Medical Center", money_received: #<BigDecimal:b6ca9318,'0.6E6',9(18)>, date_received: "2013-10-23", use_of_money: "Money used o construct operation theater.", grade_of_health_center: 4, opening_time: "2000-01-01 07:00:00", closing_time: "2000-01-01 18:30:00", **service_offered: ["2", "3", "4", ""]**, other_service_offered: "HIV treatement", male_patients: 54, female_patients: 78, brick_and_wattle: 9, mad_and_wattle: 2, other_structures: 9, source_of_power: [""], other_source_of_power: "Generator", toilet_facilities: true, alternative_disposal: "", separate_toilets: true, running_water: true, alternative_water: "", state_of_water: "Functional", duration_non_functional: "", placenta_pit: true, placental_disposal: "", waste_pit: true, waste_disposal: "", storage_expired_drugs: false, expired_drugs_storage: "They are burnt to ash", pregnant_mother: 15, number_of_beds: 5, delivery_beds: 1, ambulance: true, status_of_ambulance: "Functional", keep_records: true, number_of_staff: 14, medical_staff: 6, resident_medical_staff: 3, created_at: "2014-10-23 17:00:48", updated_at: "2014-10-23 21:23:36">
```

How can i check the value `service_offered: ["2", "3", "4", ""]` for existence of '2'

I have tried this;

```
Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '2'").includes(service_offered: "4").count
```

**I want to retrieve the records having service_offered array containing value 2**

Comment: please clarify one thing ** you want to retrieve the records having service_offered array containing value 2** or **you want to search for value 2 in service offered field in the record list of `Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '2'")` this command? **

Comment: @anusha **I want to retrieve the records having service_offered array containing value 2**

Comment: try this: `count = 0
Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '4'").each do |health|
   if health.service_offered.include?('2')
       count = count + 1
   end 
end `

Comment: try this  mostly it will work: `Health.where("array_to_string(ticket_code) like ?","%2%" )` please let me know it works or not

Comment: @anusha I have tried `Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '1' AND array_to_string(service_offered) like ?","%1%"").includes(offered_service: "1").count` and it does not work

Comment: why again `includes?` and did you get any error messages

Comment: @anusha, sorry i meant this `Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '1' AND array_to_string(service_offered) like ?","%1%").count
` there is no response

Comment: Do you have records with value "1" in your database

Comment: @anusha yes there are quite a number

Comment: which database you are using, it will work for postgresql database

Comment: If it is postgresql db change the query like this: `Health.where("grade_of_health_center = '1' AND array_to_string(service_offered, ',') like ?", "%1%").count`